# How can I write a SELECT statement in which the condition is the result of a function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write a SELECT statement as follows:

```
SELECT field_a 
FROM my_table
WHERE field_b IN (my_function(field_c)).
```

Is that possible?

`my_function` would have to return an array?

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  field_a, field_b, my_function(field_c) fc
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   field_b = fc
```

The return type of your function should be `SETOF` (e. g. `SETOF INT`, `SETOF VARCHAR` etc.)

Note that you can use an `IN` style expression like this:

```
SELECT  field_a, field_b
FROM    mytable
WHERE   field_b IN (SELECT my_function(field_c))
```

, but if your function returns a complex type, the former style is preferrable, since you can compare to one field of the complex type and return the other within one query, like this:

```
FUNCTION my_function RETURNS SETOF anothertable

/* This will return a set of records of same layout as in table "anothertable" */

SELECT  field_a, field_b, fc.column1, fc.column2
FROM    (
        SELECT  field_a, field_b, my_function(field_c) fc
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   field_b = fc.column1
```

We compare with `column1` here and return both `column1` and `column2`.

This would be impossible with a correlated subquery.

Comment: You're right about the SETOF return type, but the example query could be simpler - "... WHERE field_b IN (SELECT my_function(field_c))".

Comment: Simpler is not better. Subselects especially with a function would be a performance killer. A derived table is almost always preferred over a subselect.

Answer (score 0):

As long as my_function's return type is just a result set with the same type as field_b (like Varchar(20) or int), then you should be fine.